# MVC - Strip unwanted text from rss feed

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, rss, orchardcms

Ive got the following code in my RSS consumer (Vandelay Industries RemoteRSS) in my Orchard CMS implementation:

```
@using System.Xml.Linq
@{
  var feed = Model.Feed as XElement;
 }
<ul>
@foreach(var item in feed
.Element("channel")
.Elements("item")
.Take((int)Model.ItemsToDisplay)) 
{
 <li>@T(item.Element("description").Value)</li>
}
</ul>
```

The rss feed Im using is from Pinterest, and this bundles the image, link, and a short description all inside the 'description' elements of the feed.

```
<description>&lt;a href="/pin/215609900882251703/"&gt;&lt;img src="http://media-cache-ec2.pinterest.com/upload/88664686384961121_UIyVRN8A_b.jpg"&gt;&lt;/a&gt;How to install Orchard CMS on IIS Server</description>
```

My issue is that I don't want the text bits, and I also need to prefix the 'href=' links with 'http://www.pinterest.com'.

I've managed to edit the original code with my newbie skills to the above,, which essentially displays the images as links which are only relative and thus pointing locally to my server. These images are also then followed by the short description.

So to summarise, I need a way to prefix all links with 'http://pinterest.com' and then to remove the fee text after the image/links.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably parse the description, with something like http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/, and then tweak it to add the prefix. Or you can learn regular expression and do without a library. Could be a little trickier and error-prone however.

Comment: Any suggestions on where to look for the Regex stuff? Im probably not looking in the right places, but having trouble finding the right stuff. Initially Im interested in the methodology, I can work out the actual REGEX needed later.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link. I dont tend to find the msdn stuff very helpful, i guess my brain just doesnt work the right way for the microsoft documentation. I just wondered if you knew of any good resources / points of reference, and whether you had any posts about it on your helpful blog.

Comment: Not directly on that, no. I usually find regexplib.com pretty useful with their database of regular expression examples.